# How to pass page as an argument in the function parameter of page.evaluate()?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, dom-events, puppeteer

I am getting this error when I pass page as an argument:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'BrowserContext'
    |     property '_browser' -> object with constructor 'Browser'
    --- property '_defaultContext' closes the circle Are you passing a nested JSHandle?
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
```

My corresponding code is:

```
const result = await page.evaluate = ( async (page, selector1, selector2) => {
    let result = [];
    const sel = document.querySelectorAll(selector1);  
    if(sel.length) {
        const total = sel.length;
        for(let i=0;i<total;i++) {
            result.push(document.querySelector(selector1 + ` div:nth-child(${i+1}) span a`).textContent);
            await page.click(selector2 + ` div:nth-child(${i+1})`);
        }
    }
    return result;       
}, page, selector1, selector2);
```

How do I include the page argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you understand how the `.evaluate` method works. This method executes the code in the browser context, so to click on an element, **you can use such code as if you were writing it in a browser**. You cannot pass complex objects like `page` between the browser and `Node.js`. I changed your code inside the `.evaluate` method, it should look something like this:

```
const result = await page.evaluate((selector1, selector2) => {
    const result = [];
    const sel = document.querySelectorAll(selector1);  
    if (sel.length) {
        const total = sel.length;
        for (let i = 0; i<total; i++) {
            result.push(sel.querySelector(`div:nth-child(${i+1})`).textContent);
            document.querySelector(`${selector2} div:nth-child(${i+1})`).click();
        }
    }
    return result;       
}, selector1, selector2);
```

Comment: Ohh nice. Now I know how **.evaluate** works. 
Thanks for the help.